# Birdman and In Bruges, dream sequence reference

Tags: birdman, in-bruges

Something is been bugging me since I saw Birdman. when they were discussing about the budget and Galifianakis complained that the reserve is gone on the trees, Keaton replied its for a dream sequence with dwarves and also made a point on them not being called dwarves any more. (cant remember/find the exact quote!)

**Is there a chance they are referencing or making a connection with In Bruges?**

There was also a dream sequence, with dwarves, and there is also the discussion where they don't like that term

Is it just coincidence??

Quotes from **In Bruges**:

> Chloë: He doesn't like being called a midget. He prefers dwarf.
>
> Ray: This is exactly my point! People going around calling you a
>   midget when you want to be called a dwarf. Of course you're going to
>   blow your head off.

---

> Ray: [...] They're filming midgets!

---

> Chloë: It's a Dutch movie. Its a dream
>                       sequence. Its a pastiche of Nicolas
>                       Roeg'S 'Dont Look Now'. Not a
>                       pastiche, but a ...'homage' is too
>                       strong...A 'Nod of the Head'.

It might be that I like both movies quite a lot and I'm just making stuff up! :D

Comment: I doubt there is any link apart from the similarity of the dialogue, this is just a general quote, no different from Big Lebowski [*Asian-American*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Wu598ENenk)

Comment: I feel like you are talking about an obvious/well known thing which am missing can you elaborate what you mean with "Big Lebowski American-Asian"? :D (I did watch big lebowski)

Comment: The point being it's common for people to say, *you can't say that* or *the correct nomenclature is Asian American*

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is any connection, this is just a normal line that people would say that *you can't say that*, no different to the [*the correct nomenclature is Asian-American*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Wu598ENenk) from Big Lebowski.

[Additionally there have been some instances where usage of such terms has been censored](http://forums.digitalspy.co.uk/showthread.php?t=1264837) (on TV at least).

The comment to me in Birdman and In Bruges is just a Political Correctness remark.

Comment: hm it just occurred to me that you are not considering both similarities but only the part for midgets. The point is that they both have dream sequences with midgets, and also make the same discussion. I agree that the midget discussion only would not mean anything. But common, a dream sequence, with midgets, in both films!

Comment: I think that is also a coincidence too, I can't find any reference online connecting the two films, the use of dwarfs to portray some element of freakishness or weird dream like scene has been used many times, [Twin peaks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=guwl1w0yFGk) and [Living in Oblivion](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0113677/quotes)